# Convierta los resultados de los productos Mysql a json con php

Tags: php, json

Estoy desarrollando un e-commerce con php y mysql. Quiero hacer este proyecto multiplataforma, comenzando con Android. Para esto estaré usando Java para recuperar estos valores en json. ¿Cómo puedo generar un json desde una tabla mysql para crear mi API? La estructura principal de la tabla mysql que usar é es:

```
NombreProduto | ValorProduto | ValorPromocao | Descripcion
```

En PHP lo estoy usando así:

```
<?php
function public listarProdutos()
{
  ...
  $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexão,"SELECT * FROM products");
  $resultado = array();
  while($pd = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    $resultado[0] = array("Nombre Produto" => $pd["NombreProduto"],
                          "Valor Produto"  => $pd["ValorProduto"],
                          "Valor Promocao" => $pd["NombrePromocao"],
                          "Descripcion"    => $pd["Descripcion"]);
  }
 return json_encode($resultado); 
}
...
?>
```

Pero no sé si es el camino correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Diria que tan solo estás conservando un único valor dentro de `$resultado`, en el índice **0**, pues lo estás sobreescribiendo todo el rato.

Creo que lo deberías hacer así:

```
<?php
function public listarProdutos()
{
  ...
  $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexão,"SELECT * FROM products");
  $resultado = array();
  while($pd = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    $resultado[] = array("Nombre Produto" => $pd["NombreProduto"],
                          "Valor Produto"  => $pd["ValorProduto"],
                          "Valor Promocao" => $pd["NombrePromocao"],
                          "Descripcion"    => $pd["Descripcion"]);
  }
 return json_encode($resultado); 
}
...
?>
```

para que te guarde bien todos los resultados y después puedas recorrerlo allí donde lo necesites en formato json. Mediante `$resultado[]` lo que estamos haciendo es agregar un elemento más al array **$resultado** en lugar de sobreescribirlo.